# How do I dynamically compare data in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around 70 tables that have the same structure (only the columns change, but always start with CURRENT_DATE and ID) and I would like to make some function or procedure that would help me speed up the process of checking the data, if its uploaded correctly or if something is new.

Tables structure likes something like this:

| CURRENT_DATE | ID | Column1 | Column2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.2.2O23 | 1 | some text | some value | some text |
| 12.2.2O23 | 2 | some text | some value | some text |
| 12.2.2O23 | 3 | some text | some value | some text |
| .... | ... | some text | some value | some text |
| 21.11.2O23 | 1 | some text | some value | some text |
| 21.11.2O23 | 2 | some text | some value | some text |
| 21.11.2O23 | 3 | some text | some value | some text |

I would like to do something where I would input table_name, columns, date1, date2 (dates where I want to compare the data) and the output would be something like this.

| STATUS | ID | Column1 | Column2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NEW | 50 | some text | some value | some text |
| NEW | 270 | some text | some value | some text |
| CHANGED | 15 | some text | some value | some text |

So my question is, how would you handle this? Using two cursors and then comparing the dynamic data would insert data? Or is there a much simpler way?
I'm trying to learn SQL but I'm not sure how to do this and I don't want to write each SQL script by hand for 70 tables.

Thank you everyone and have a nice day!

Comment: Look into the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement in PL/SQL. Put together the SQL for each table in a loop and insert results to a table.

Comment: Are you aware, that you used `21.11.2O23` with an [O](https://codepoints.net/U+004F) rather than [0](https://codepoints.net/U+0030)?

Comment: I had a very similar question for Teradata years back that JNevill gave an excellent answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655561/parametrize-columns-in-select-statement/36656687#36656687 . You can probably use that for inspiration, just changing the Teradata system views (dbc.tables, dbc.columns) to the Oracle analogues (all_tables, all_columns) and PL/SQL syntax.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit OMG, I am sorry that was my very bad mistype :D

Comment: @PaulW thank you for your response. I will have a look at it :)

Comment: Isn't this the kind of things that Debezium or Flyway were built for?

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for your response, but I didn't know about these systems, but I still want to make some procedure/function and learn it by myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/1Dv0aiDG

Oof, started writing this before remembering what an eye sore dynamic sql is.

Chris Saxon's answer is very good. And probably what I'd do too. It has the big advantage that the results don't have to be objects in the system views. But having to pass in static column names might not be a general as you are looking for.

This assumes that the table pairs have corresponding names _baseline and _compare. Of course this probably isn't your case, but handling your actual names should be trivial.

Each iteration of the table cursor results in a comparison string whole_query_new_and_changed which you can do with what you see fit. Execute immediate or save off somewhere.

Be wary of NULLs in the compare condition. Usually I'll do

```
field1 <> field2 
Or (field1 is null and field2 is not null) 
or (field2 is not null and field2 is null).
```

But didn't feel like doing all that typing here.

There are some dummy strings just so the constructions work, ex 1=1 or (1=2). You can trim these out later on if you want it looking cleaner.

Also note that, depending on how this is used sql injection is always something to keep in mind.

Lastly, if this was going to be production code and I didn't want my coworker's eyes bleeding I would do this in python or some other language connecting to Oracle. Much easier to keep readable than dynamic PL/SQL.

```
create table some_test_data_baseline
   ( id integer,
     column1 varchar(50),
     column2 varchar(50)
   );

create table some_test_data_compare
  ( id integer,
    column1 varchar(50),
    column2 varchar(50)
  );

insert into some_test_data_baseline values (1,'some changed text','some other changed test');
insert into some_test_data_baseline values (2,'new text','some other new test');
insert into some_test_data_baseline values (3,'unchanged text','some other unchanged test');
insert into some_test_data_compare values (1,'some text','some other test');
insert into some_test_data_compare values (3,'unchanged text','some other unchanged test');

declare
  changed_query VARCHAR2(10000);
  new_query VARCHAR2(10000);
  compare_table_name VARCHAR2(255);
  whole_query_new_and_changed VARCHAR2(10000);
  columns_in_table VARCHAR2(10000);
  TYPE cur_cur IS REF CURSOR;
  v_col_cur cur_cur;
  all_columns_query VARCHAR2(2500);
  col_name VARCHAR2(255);
  select_col_list VARCHAR2(2500);
  difference_condition VARCHAR2(2500);
begin
  for table_cur in
    (
     select table_name
       from all_tables
      where upper(table_name) like '%_BASELINE'
    )
  loop
    all_columns_query := 'SELECT column_name 
                            FROM all_tab_columns
                           where table_name = ''' || table_cur.table_name || '''';
    select_col_list := '';
    difference_condition := '';
    changed_query := '';
    OPEN v_col_cur FOR all_columns_query;
       LOOP
       FETCH v_col_cur INTO col_name;
       EXIT WHEN v_col_cur%NOTFOUND;
       select_col_list := select_col_list || 't1.' || col_name || ',';
       difference_condition := difference_condition || ' (t1.' || col_name || ' <> t2.' || col_name || ') OR ';
       END LOOP;
       select_col_list := select_col_list || 'terminated';
       select_col_list := replace(select_col_list,',terminated','');
    CLOSE v_col_cur;
   difference_condition := difference_condition || ' (1=2) ';
   compare_table_name := replace(table_cur.table_name,'_BASELINE','_COMPARE');
   changed_query := 'SELECT ''CHANGED'' as description, ' || select_col_list || ' FROM ' || table_cur.table_name  || ' t1 ' || 
                    ' INNER JOIN ' || compare_table_name || ' t2 
                       ON t1.id = t2.id ' || 
                    ' WHERE (1 = 2) OR ' || difference_condition;
   new_query := 'SELECT ''NEW'' as description, ' || select_col_list || ' from ' || table_cur.table_name || ' t1 ' ||
                '  where not exists ( select 1 from ' || compare_table_name || ' t2 ' ||
                '                        where t1.id = t2.id )';
   whole_query_new_and_changed := changed_query || ' 
     UNION 
     ' || new_query;
   dbms_output.put_line(whole_query_new_and_changed);
   END LOOP;

end;

-- Single iteration's output, formatted.
SELECT
  'CHANGED' as description,
  t1.ID,
  t1.COLUMN1,
  t1.COLUMN2
FROM
  SOME_TEST_DATA_BASELINE t1
  INNER JOIN SOME_TEST_DATA_COMPARE t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  (1 = 2)
  OR (t1.ID <> t2.ID)
  OR (t1.COLUMN1 <> t2.COLUMN1)
  OR (t1.COLUMN2 <> t2.COLUMN2)
  OR (1 = 2)
UNION
SELECT
  'NEW' as description,
  t1.ID,
  t1.COLUMN1,
  t1.COLUMN2
from
  SOME_TEST_DATA_BASELINE t1
where
  not exists (
    select
      1
    from
      SOME_TEST_DATA_COMPARE t2
    where
      t1.id = t2.id
  )
```

Comment: Hello @Error_2646, thank you for recommendation on how to handle my question! It looks for me the closest as I thought of it. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you again :) Have a nic day!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on 19.7 or higher, you can build a table SQL macro to do this.

This essentially enables you to create a query template you can pass tables &  columns to. So it's a matter deciding which method you'd like to use to compare the tables.

There are [several methods you can use to compare tables](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-compare-two-tables-to-get-the-different-rows-with-sql):

- Set operations (`union` & `minus`)
- Unioning the tables together, grouping the result, & returning rows with a count mismatch
- `full outer join`s returning the unmatched rows

Here's an example macro using the `group by` method for the template query:

```
create or replace function compare_tables ( 
  t1 dbms_tf.table_t, t2 dbms_tf.table_t, comparison_columns dbms_tf.columns_t
) return clob sql_macro as
  stmt clob;
  column_list clob;
begin

  for col in 1 .. comparison_columns.count loop
    column_list := column_list || comparison_columns ( col ) || ',';
  end loop;
  column_list := rtrim ( column_list, ',' );
  
  stmt := q'!
  select ##COLUMNS##,
         case 
           when sum ( t1 ) > sum ( t2 ) then 't1'
           else 't2'
         end as source_table
  from   (
    select t1.*, 1 t1, 0 t2 from t1
    union  all
    select t2.*, 0 t1, 1 t2 from t2
  )
  group  by ##COLUMNS##
  having sum ( t1 ) <> sum ( t2 ) !';
  
  stmt := replace ( stmt, '##COLUMNS##', column_list );

  return stmt;
end compare_tables;
/
```

Call this the `from` clause. Pass the names of the tables you want to compare along with a list of column names in the `columns` operator.

The tables can be physical tables, views, or named subqueries:

```
with t1 as (
  select level c1, date'2023-01-01' + level c2 from dual
  connect by level <= 5
),  t2 as (
  select level + 1 c1, date'2023-01-01' + level + 1 c2 from dual
  connect by level <= 5
)
  select * from compare_tables ( 
    t1, t2, columns ( c1, c2 ) 
  );
/* 
        C1 C2                SO
---------- ----------------- --
         1 02-JAN-2023 00:00 t1
         6 07-JAN-2023 00:00 t2
*/  

create table employees as
  select * from hr.employees where department_id = 60
  fetch first 3 rows only;
  
with t1 as (
  select * from hr.employees where department_id = 60
),  t2 as (
  select * from employees where department_id = 60
)
  select * from compare_tables ( 
    t1, employees, 
    columns ( employee_id, first_name, last_name  ) 
  );
/*

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 SO
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- --
        106 Valli                Pataballa                 t1
        107 Diana                Lorentz                   t1
*/
```

Comment: Hello @Chris, Thank you for your blog, where you describe different methods of comparing data in table and for your comment. I will have a look and will try it. Have a wonderful day!